# jQuery UI datepicker function override

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, localization, datepicker

How can I override jQuery UI datepicker functions and make it pass 31 days for each month? I need this change for localization.
I used the following code to change `_getDaysInMonth` return value but no success.

```
$.datepicker._getDaysInMonth = function(fyear, fmonth){
        return 31;
    };
```

jQuery UI datepicker should shows 31 days for each month, for example the 4th month(April) by default is 30 days but I need jQuery shows 31 days blocks.
Thanks.

Comment: you want April 31st to be selectable ??

Comment: Yes, for all months 31st day should be selectable.